# Eclipse install broken

Tags: eclipse

I tried recently to install eclipse on my Desktop computer. It looked great the very first time when I launched it from the installer, but as soon as I tried to make a new project, it crashed. I then tried to open eclipse up, only to find that it looked like it does in the picture attached. Is there  fix to this bug, have you ever experienced this, and if so, do you know how to fix it? I have tried to install it multiple locations, and it still does the same thing.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: This isn't the sort of question that usually gets allowed here.

Comment: @JimW Where should I bring my question?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. My hunch is that you have a problem with unity, so you might want to go to askubuntu. I'm using eclipse on ubuntu (14.04) and windows 10 and windows 7 without seeing this problem.

Comment: @JimW I'm not using Unity, I'm using KDE on Slackware

Comment: Eclipse looks like it is behaving like the contents of GUI elements are larger than they actually are. I'm not a unix front end guy so I have no clue why it might be doing this. But I'm very doubtful your problem is coming from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

googled this: eclipse kde appearance broken

found this-> https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164851

dunno if it's what you're looking for